# Upload zip file via Dropbox Api and curl

Tags: curl, zip, command-line-interface, dropbox-api

I'm trying to upload .zip file using

- [dropbox api](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-api-v2-explorer/#files_upload)
- curl
- bash script

Curl request:

```
curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload \
--header "Authorization: Bearer <Access Token>" \
--header "Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"path\": \"/upload.zip\"}" \
--header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
--data-binary @/upload.zip
```

Uploading completed without errors. Downloading from another device (Ubuntu server) is also completed. But when I'm trying yo unzip I get bellow error:

```
Archive:  upload.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of upload.zip or
        upload.zip.zip, and cannot find upload.zip.ZIP, period.
```

Something is not correct in my curl upload configuration I guess. Probably, there are some special config to upload and download .zip files.

What I'm doing wrong? How to upload .zip file via dropbox api in the reight way?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/Upload-zip-file-via-Dropbox-Api-and-curl/m-p/340525#M19734 ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After one day I've found what was wrong.
As most of unworking situation, you have to check your code and syntax...

1) file path shall be inside quotes:

```
--data-binary @"/upload.zip"
```

2) download path shall start with slash:

```
curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer <Token>" \
    --header "Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"path\": \"/directory/upload.zip\"}" >>upload.zip
```

Generaly it's a good idea to check, if downloaded zip file hase the right file size. If file size is not the same as in local storage so uploading was not finished successfully.